# Hello. I am trying to create a project in laravel with login/logout for users and admin.I have take users model

Tags: php, laravel-6

I have create adminLoginController[adminLoginController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqBKF.png)

this is web.php[web.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0WBI.png)
and I take this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v57qN.png)
I can't understand where is the problem

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Answer (score 0):

in the Route in `web.php` replace the `/` with `\`

Comment: if I change / with \ Its one more error. Does't change nothing :(

Comment: have you generated that controller with `php artisan make:controller Auth/AdminLoginController` ?

Comment: yes.it gives to me one problem here 
c:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapps\kreatx>php artisan route:list

   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class ('App\Http\Controllers\Auth/AdminLoginController, [] )

  at C:\xampp\htdocs\laravelapps\kreatx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php:806

Comment: can you please delete that Controller, generate again with `php artisan make:controller Auth/AdminLoginController`, change the / to \ in the route just to be sure that wasn't some strange configuration error?

Comment: also found that if you have Controllers in subfolders of App/Http/Controllers, if you run `composer dumpautoload` you than don't have to write the "fubfolder\" in the routes, but i'm not sure if it's a great method to do it

Comment: its okay now.Thnx a lot :)

Comment: try to delete all the files in bootstrap/cache